# Issue's containing, "onClick" and a getIntExtra

Tags: java, android

I am having issues getting this to work, here is what I am trying to get to: an onClickListener that will get the state of the radio and return a toast. But I am messing up somewhere. I am having an issue with the intent, anyone able to shed some light on this?the intent is not able to be resolved. (Yes, I obviously have imported it.) Here is what I have:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
protected Intent intent;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button check = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    check.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            getIntent();
            int state= intent.getIntExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE, -1);
            String msg=null;
                    switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }

    });
}
```

}

Comment: What (incorrect) output/functionality are you seeing at the moment?  And what is expected behaviour of the the `Toast.makeText` call?

Comment: What does LogCat say about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't store the value returned by getIntent(). This is better :

```
public void onClick(View v){
        intent = getIntent();
        int state= intent.getIntExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE, -1);
```

Comment: Okay, this has solved the FC, thank you much! 
But now onto the next issue, I am not getting a return value. ( I have more cases under my switch, but have not pasted them just to save space on the page). Should I?

Comment: As well, nothing is being printed in the log when the Button is pressed.

Comment: Try this : `intent = MainActivity.this.getIntent()`

Comment: Both methods work, but my issue persists that after the onClick, nothing is returned in the log or on screen. I know this is a completely different issue now, but I would likely appreciate the help.

Comment: Look here, you need to use getStringExtra instead of getIntExtra : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#EXTRA_STATE But I wonder if it's really the field you want to use. It has nothing to do with network types.

Comment: What other method would you suggest for getting the state of the radio?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to call `show()`
[manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#show%28%29)

example

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

Another thing is indeed in this line

```
int state=intent.getIntExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE, -1);
```

What is "intent" here? Is it declared somewhere in the class?

You say in the comment that you're getting a forceclose in this line. Is it a nullpointer? Do you need to call `getIntent()` somewhere maybe? Is that 'intent' initialized?

Comment: Okay yes, that was an obvious mistake I made, but not the issue that I am having :(

Comment: well, what _is_ the issue you are having? Can you post something to hold on to, like an error?

Comment: My issue is that I just get FC as soon as the button is pressed, and it points to the line containing the intent.